# How to make a part of string bold in a in a UI label

Tags: string, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to make bold some part of a big string. I am using Xamarin iOS and getting a big string from API. I need to make some part of the string as bold I tried `<b>some text </b>` this will not work for mono touch. What is the best option to make a string bold in run time in xamrin. iOS or in winforms applications?

Answer (score 3):

Use `AttributedString` to apply attributes to different parts of the string. See example below that will only make the first half of the string bold

```
var BoldString = new NSMutableAttributedString (original_string);

var BoldTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes {
    Font = UIFont.FromName ("Helvetica-Bold", 20f)
   };

BoldString.SetAttributes (BoldTextAttributes.Dictionary, new NSRange (0, OutOfStock.Length / 2)); // this range will apply the attribute only to the first half of the string

MyLabel.AttributedText = BoldString; // Assign the attributed text to your label
```